# Find maximum in a matrix while taking care of the tie case [in C]

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

I am trying to find the maximum value within a matrix. I did it like this in C:

```
int max = matrix[0][0], max_i = 0, max_j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if(matrix[i][j] > max) {
            max = matrix[i][j];
            max_i = i;
            max_j = j;
        } 
    }
}
```

But what if I'd like to know if there is a tie? In that case I would like my function to return `-1`.  I though to use another variable to hold the second highest value, but in that case, I'll need to use another two variables: second_max_i and second_max_j (the code gets messy).

I know how to do it with another two loops (iterate to find second place and compare), but is there a way to do it only with two loops (instead of four)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by keeping track if you come across another element with the same value as your current max. If you do, set a "tie" flag. Whenever you find a new max value, clear the "tie flag", as below:

```
int max = matrix[0][0], max_i = 0, max_j = 0, tie = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if(matrix[i][j] == max) {
            tie = 1;
        }
        else if(matrix[i][j] > max) {
            max = matrix[i][j];
            tie = 0;
            max_i = i;
            max_j = j;
        } 
    }
}
```

Then you can return -1 if `tie == 1`.

Edit to add: Note that with the current code, you initialize `int max = matrix[0][0]`, and the first element you inspect is also `matrix[0][0]`. Thus if `matrix[0][0]` is your max element, you will falsely detect a tie. To prevent this, if you know the matrix will never contain a value lower than a some value, you could initialize `max` to a value lower than that. For instance, if you can guarantee the matrix will only contain non-negative integers, you could initialize `int max = -1`.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply. could you specify what is `max_pair`? didn't' find where it was initialized. `dancers` were a mistake. it should have been `matrix`.

Comment: @vesii: You used `max_pair` in your original question. You tell me. :) I have edited my answer to show my assumption that `max_pair` should read `max`.

Comment: @vesii: I see you have since edited your question to match my assumptions regarding your variable names. I will edit my comment to remove mention of them as well, so as not to confuse others.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below code snippet:

```
int dancers = [[1,2], [3,4]];
int max = -1, max_i = -1, max_j = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        if(matrix[i][j] > max) {
            max = dancers[i][j];
            max_i = i;
            max_j = j;
        } 
        else if(matrix[i][j] == max){
            max_i = -1;
            max_j = -1;
        }
    }
}

if(max_i == -1 && max_j == -1){
  max = -1;
}
```

Now you can check max if there is any winner, if it's -1 then there's tie.